# How do i make .Include to work on an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm having trouble running a query on my repository. I have to fetch a product by the id and display it in an edit view alongside the image of the product.

There is a method in my ProductRepository that implements Get() i.e fetch all the product and GetByID as the name implies. I implemented a generic repository pattern with a unit of work class like below

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal SchoolContext context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public GenericRepository(SchoolContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }
```

I think thats the only relevant code block. The problem arises when i try to run a query that i found in a tutorial to fetch the product alongside the image with the query below

```
Product product = db.Products.Include(s => s.Files).SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
```

I cant use db.Products because i'm using a unit of work class so i have to run the query with `_unit.ProductRepository.GetByID().Include(s => s.Files).SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);`

However this does not seem to be possible and i'm stucked.

Comment: Given that you've got an "include properties" don't you just want `Get(includeProperties: "Files")`?

Comment: Do you mean `Get()` rather than `GetByID()` in your final piece of code? Because `GetByID()` should always have a parameter passed to it.

Comment: The whole point of the repository that you've created is to prevent the consumer of it from being able to use LINQ.  It's *goal* is to prevent you from doing any operation but the limited subset of functionality provided.  Thus your options become rather obvious, either don't use it, use the limited functionality exposed to you, or expand the type to support the functionality that you want it to as a part of the limited subset of LINQ it supports.

Comment: maybe I missed something, doesn't :
`_unit.ProductRepository.Get(s => s.ID == id, null, "Files").SingleOrDefault();` do the trick ?

Answer (score 3):

You can not use Include with a IEnumerable, It only works with IQueryable, when you invoke in your repository `query.ToList();` you query is retrieved from database to memory in a IEnumerable and when your data is in memory Include doesn't work.

You can pass the objects that you want to include in your query as a parameter like you do with filter or order in your Get method.

You can override your ProductRepository method

```
    public override Product GetByID(object ID)
    {
        return db.Products.Include(p => p.Files).SingleOrDefault(p => p.ID == ID);
    }
```

or if you don't want always to return Files

```
    public override Product GetByID(object ID, List<string> includes)
    {

        var query = db.Products.AsQueryable();
        foreach (string include in includes)
        {
            query = query.Include(include);
       }

       return query.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ID == ID);
    }
```

And invoke like

```
 Product product = new ProductRepository().GetByID(IDProduct, new List<string>() { "Files" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DbSet<TEntity> set = dbSet;

foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
    (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    set = set.Include(includeProperty);
}

IQueryable<TEntity> query = set;

if (filter != null)
{
    query = query.Where(filter);
}
```