# Using LINQ to "transform" two models on a single View Model

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm creating a page on ASP.NET and want to pass some models (EF) to the view.
This view has information from two different models, so, I created a ViewModel for this.

First, my two models:

```
public class Database
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Host { get; set; }
  public string Schema { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Database> Databases { get; set; }
}
```

So, looking at my models, I have a `Database` that has one or more `Group`, and `Group` has one or more `Database`, so, it's a many-to-many relationship.

My view show a form with all fields from `Database` model, plus, a checkbox list with all `Group`, and if this `Group` belongs to the `Database`, the checkbox is checked.

So, I created the following View Model (suggestions are welcome):

```
public class DatabaseViewModel
{
  public Database Database { get; set; }
  public List<DatabaseGroupViewModel> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class DatabaseGroupViewModel
{
  public Group Group { get; set; }
  public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

I used "directly" the `Database` and `Group` because this is a CRUD form, and validations was on model already (Data Annotations). The ideia here is get the `Database`, and all `Group`, and if this `Group` belongs to the `Database`, the `Selected` property must be `true`.

So far so good.

I used the following code to list all `Group`, and set `Selected` property as `true` if the `Group` belongs to the `Database`.

```
int databaseId = 1; // just for example
DatabaseViewModel model = new DatabaseViewModel
{
  Database = await Context.Databases.FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Id == databaseId),
  Groups = Context.Groups.Include(d => d.Databases).OrderBy(g => g.Name).Select(g => new DatabaseGroupViewModel
  {
    Group = g,
    Selected = g.Databases.Any(d => d.Id == databaseId)
  }).ToList()
};
```

This appear to be working, but I don't know if is the best approach.

Any help?

Edit: working code now

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872837/how-do-i-make-include-to-work-on-an-ienumerable

Comment: Please do not edit your question in ways that _change_ the question, as you have done here. Your original question involved code that didn't work and which you want to try to get to work. Your new question completely changes the implementation, and asks a completely different question from what you originally asked.

Comment: sorry, but my question is not about my not working code, but if this approach is correct, and if not, how to make things more "cleaner".

Comment: Your original question _was_ about your "not working code". That's my point. You now have a new question, which is completely different from what you originally posted here. See the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44032223/revisions) if you have any doubt about that.

Comment: "cleaner"... Just pass `Context.Database.Include(d=>d.Groups).First(d=>d.Id==databaseId)` as your viewmodel `(Models.Database)`, and toss the possible groups into the Viewbag.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that Peter Duniho! (I voted to close this question because of this)! :(

Comment: Robert McKee, yes, this way is more "cleaner", but not the "best" (or at least good).

Comment: @RobertoCorreia What makes you think that it isn't the "best"?  You are passing the database to the view, and the possible options.  "Selected" is likely a View-related issue and shouldn't be in the model for example.  If you really want, create a ViewModel like: `MyViewModel { public Database Database {get;set;} public IEnumerable<Group> Groups {get;set;}}`  My original suggestion will definitely scale/perform better than the other suggested solutions to boot.

Comment: @RobertMcKee, I think in this way, I have to check if checkbox is selected or not on View, and I really don't like to do this "directly" in the view. Sure I can use ViewBag, or a model with all groups, but in some place, I must check if that checkbox of the group must be selected or not, and in my opinion, do this on the View is bad.

Comment: @RobertoCorreia It depends on how you look at it, I suppose.  I see it as the view is responsible for taking a model and doing whatever it needs to with that model to be able to display it, and then send back another model to the user.  What if you decide at some point down the line to not do a list of checkboxes, but use a multiselect?  That's obviously a UI change, not a data or controller change, yet it wants a list of values that are selected and a list of possible values.  Or maybe you will use a 3rd party checkboxlist renderer that uses the same.

Comment: You can use whatever interface/contract you want between the view and controller (and between the controller and the model) that you want, but to say you don't want to do something directly in the view  strikes me as rather limiting and trying to achieve that will force you to push more and more logic that is specific to your view, or how your view is implementing something into your controller as a bad design principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF transposes your linq expression into SQL to query the database, but not everything can be represented as SQL – “LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method…” is the error you get when you use something that EF can’t transpose to SQL in your query.

If you were to load the values with .ToList() first, you wouldn’t get this error since the expression will be evaluated in memory. Note that this pulls the data from the database into memory, so you should limit the data selected with an EF supported expression as far as possible prior to actualising the entities with the ToList() call.

However, in this case it’s the use of Context.Databases within the linq expression, which I think you can avoid altogether by using the Group parameter you already have going into the Select argument:

```
int databaseId = 1; // just for example
DatabaseViewModel model = new DatabaseViewModel
{
  Database = await Context.Databases.FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Id == databaseId),
  Groups = Context.Groups.OrderBy(g => g.Name).Select(g => new DatabaseGroupViewModel
  {
    Group = g,
    Selected =  g.Databases .Any(db => db.Id == databaseId)
  }).ToList()
};
```

Comment: I must include `Context.Groups.Include(g => g.Databases)` (Lazy Load)

Comment: @RobertoCorreia `.Include` is for eager loading, not lazy loading.  Lazy loading would happen if you didn't do the .Include.  It would likely be eager-loaded anyhow as it would determine that it needs the database id for the Selected property in either case, just a FYI.